# SQL*Plus Send automatic email to the personal table

Tags: plsql, triggers, sqlplus, sendmail

I want to create a trigger to send automatic emails to the mail addresses on personal table when there is a change on the other table like 'city' on SQL*Plus.
But I could not find a way to create this trigger, could you please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First: This is not SQL*Plus but Oracle SQL we are talking here - and actually you do have to write PL/SQL code for that, like in any trigger in Oracle.
But you can use SQL*Plus for that - or SQLdeveloper or any other tool which poses as database client.

How to send mails in PL/SQL:

```
UTL_MAIL.SEND ('sender@myapp.com','receiver@yourapp.com',
    message => 'this is the message',
    subject => 'Warnung: message arriving');
```

But your DBA must have configured the SMTP server for the database and you need appropriate privileges to send a mail.